# How to start running kafka connector in Open Source Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was trying to run Kafka connectors using open source apache kafka (Not using confluent)

```
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties
```

This works fine, but this way only starts the Kafka connect worker, how do I load the community connectors?

```
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties --config filesource.properties
bin/connect-distributed.sh config/connect-distributed.properties filesource.properties
```

I tried the two above commands, both give no error but fail to load the connector module.
Another question, what command do I type to check the status of the connectors?

Answer (score 0):

About checking the status of connectors, you can use curl GET command.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/connector_name/status|jq
```

jq is optional, it gives a better visualization. If you want to check all the connectors, I can recommend this script I use:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors"| jq '.[]'| xargs -I{connector_name} curl -s "http://localhost:8083/connectors/"{connector_name}"/status"| jq -c -M '[.name,.connector.state,.tasks[].state]|join(":|:")'| column -s : -t| sed 's/\"//g'| sort
```

I highly recommend using jq for this one. You should see output as "Running" "Failed" or "Unassigned" for each task.

Edit:
To create a connector:

```
curl -XPOST --header "Content-Type: application/json"  localhost:8083/connectors  -d
'{
    "name": "your_connector",
    "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "database.user": "user123"
    }
}'
```

Comment: is there a way to use native kafka commands instead of curl? also is the default local host port 8083? i believe my port was 9092 or something

Comment: I believe 9092 is the default for bootstrap server. [here](https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.0/connect/managing.html#managing-running-connectors) it says 8083 is the default for connect rest api. Also I haven't seen any other way or command to manage connectors.

Comment: "error_code": 404,
  "message": "No status found for connector connector_name"

Comment: do you know what is the command to load connector? I only manage to start the kafka connect worker.

Comment: first check which connectors are created. `curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors` should do it. if it returns nothing that means there are no connectors created. btw you should've changed the `connector_name` field with the name of your own connector.

Comment: i believe no connector were created, do i have to use curl to create a connector? is there no other command?

Comment: yes I use curl commands and added a simple one to give you the idea. but I believe it is not the only way. you can check [this](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/self-managed/userguide.html) page